Python 3 - ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'PyQt5'
I have installed pyQt5 using pip install pyqt5.
However when I open my test code:
import sys    
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, QtCore  

It is coming up with the error message:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\jessr\OneDrive\Documents\Coding Lessons\GUI.py", line 2, in <module>
    from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, QtCore
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'PyQt5'

I'm not sure how to fix it?
I tried different variations of the pip install (for example python -m pip install PyQt5 ) and checked my pip was updated.

main reason for this pip and python executable does not point to same location. try this import sys print(sys.executable) so you know from where python is getting picked, and then check pip there.

Try to install PyQt5 in the virtual environment and use it. It always works for me.
or
If you are using Pycharm, install it from the Pycharm package.
